# What is the most efficient way to write the following PHP for loop, which modifies an array, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to learn how to optimize javascript in the most efficient way possible...

I would assume it would be good practice to avoid creating references to properties wherever possible.

In PHP, if i have this Array:

```
$dataArray = [4,6,8];
```

To modify this array's values, i can write a foreach loop to return a reference to the value in that array, rather than a copy, using an ampersand like so:

```
foreach ($dataArray as &$value) {
 $value = $value / 2;
}
unset($value); // if im not mistaken, this is just cleanup

// $dataArray will now = [2,3,4]
```

Is the following the most efficient way to achieve the same result in Javascript?

```
var dataArray = [4,6,8];

for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) { 
    dataArray[i] = dataArray[i] / 2;
}

// if so, is there anything i should do to clean up the for loop to avoid memory leaks?
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: With a `for` loop. Read a manual please.

Comment: modify to what?

Comment: Apologies, ill try to be clear ... modifying the post now ...

Comment: Really, here, i am trying to learn how to write effecient javascript by avoiding creating references to properties wherever it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with parameters for index and the array. Then assign a new value to the item with the same index.

```js
var array = [4, 6, 8];

array.forEach(function (_, i, aa) {
    aa[i] /= 2;
});

console.log(array);
```

Just for completeness, you could generate a new array with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and assign it to the variable.

```js
var array = [4, 6, 8];

array = array.map(function (a) {
    return a / 2;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer ... is it necessary to do any clean up to avoid a memory leak in this example? ... does it make sense to null out aa for example? or is that redundant?

Comment: Right... i assume you are correct, there should not be a leak here .... i thought for a moment that aa should be nulled after use ... but i guess thats not necessary .... basically, im in the process of learning how to optimize javascript. I am also trying to get a grasp on all the scenarios that create memory leaks.

Comment: Have you tried googling? [Here's a good article about memory leaks in JavaScript](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/) (top result on Google when searching for "JavaScript memory leaks")

Comment: Yes, i have actually seen this, i am learning ... apologies for all the noob questions :/ not trying to frustrate anyone, just trying to learn to be as proficient as possible.